# JS заполнить массив fill vs push

Tags: javascript, массивы, node.js

Нужно создать и заполнить массив, вот два варианта но работают они по разному:

```
  this.d = new Array(7).fill(new SH());
```

или так

```
   this.d = [];
   for(let t =0;t<7;++t){
      this.d.push(new SH());
   }
```

Объясните в чем разница и в чем дело, потому что следующая функция возвращает разные результаты:

```
this.d.forEach((p, i) => {            
   p.w = returnTrueOrFalse(i);
   console.log('#i',i, p)
 })
 console.log('RES',this.d);
```

А вот результат:
первый вариант [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полный бред, все булевы поля обнулились в false. При этом числовые поля остались нормальными.

Во втором варианте все нормально и оба console.log возвращают одинаковый результат.

Я не знаю в чем ошибка. Спасибо!

Comment: `new Array(7).fill(new SH())` заполнит массив одним и тем же экземпляром `SH`, т.е. будет массив элементы которого ссылаются на один и тот же объект. можно написать так: `new Array(7).fill(0).map(() => new SH())`

Comment: @nörbörnën, понял, перенесите  в ответ пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Array.prototype.fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)**

> Метод `fill()` заполняет все элементы массива от начального до
> конечного индексов одним значением.
>
> ...
>
> Если аргумент `value`​​​​​ является объектом, тo метод `fill` заполнит
> массив ссылками на этот объект.

Таким образом, `new Array(7).fill(new SH())` заполнит массив одним и тем же экземпляром `SH`, т.е. будет массив элементы которого ссылаются на один и тот же объект.

Для решения вашей задачи через метод `fill()` можно сделать так:

```
new Array(7).fill(0).map(() => new SH())
```